# Google Oauth2: Is it possible to retrieve token information from an expired access token?

Tags: access-token, google-oauth

I have a Google App Engine endpoints projects which is protected by Oauth2. I saw some request has failed due to Invalid token.

Request URL: https://example.appspot.com/_ah/api/mm/v1/list?filter=q%3Dtest&alt=json
Method: example.resource.list
Error Code: 401
Reason: required
Message: Invalid token.

I could log out the token from the HEADER of the request.
The token I get is access token, format like, ya29.vwGg-....

When I tried with 
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=
to find out token information, like issue_to, client_id, extra.

It returns back with
{
error: "invalid_token",
error_description: "Invalid Value"
}

I have tested with 
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
the url returns back the same error if the token has been expired.

My guess for the reason my request has failed is the token used has expired.
But not 100% sure.

Is there way to find token info about expired access token?
Or maybe more widely, 
is there any way to find more info about invalid access token, like why it is invalid or anything else?

Comment: what to you mean by "invalid access token"? All access tokens are valid, until they expire.

Comment: It means a token , if querying use https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token= and returns back with "invalid_token" error.   Most likely, it's a expired token.

Answer (score 0):

I remove google account and add google account, then login works.

Google's guide for Google Sign-In for Android on [how to Authenticate with a backend server.](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint)

A simple way is to check the token, XYZ123 is your token

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get token information. Generally token will be invalid for various reasons so of the important reasons are Invalid Signature and Token expired. You can use https://jwt.io to decode your token and get the info. Your error description clearly tells the reason about why your token is considered invalid. Try deep diving into the code and see why it says invalid value.